# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of null

Tags: jquery, javascript

I've been trying to implement this piece of javascript in a web app I am building. It is supposed to pull data from a json-file and then create options with the names in a selector tag. In my console I first get the first piece of data logged. The row "selector.add(option);" then returns "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of null ".

The reason I am going through three layers like this is bacause I am accessing data within levels of arrays, and I'm not sure how to do it in a better way).

Does anybody know what is wrong?

```
 $.getJSON( '../names.json', function( data ) {
      $.each( data, function( key, val) {
        $.each( val, function( key2, val2) {
            $.each( val2, function( key3, val3) {
                if (key3 == "name"){
                var selector = document.getElementById("in");
                var option = document.createElement("option") 
                  option.text = val3;
                  option.value = val3;
                  console.log(option);
                  selector.add(option);
                        };
                });
            });

     });
 });
```

Comment: `var selector = document.getElementById("in");` does an element with this ID exists?
console.log(selector)

Comment: is this in a dom ready state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that `selector` and `option` variables are DOM elements but you're treating them both as though they are jQuery collections. Consider using the following:

```
    if (key3 == "name"){
        var selector = $("#in");
        var option = $("option") 
        option.text( val3 );
        option.val( val3 );
        console.log(option);
        selector.add(option);
    }
```